# ExtJS change font color of a itemm from a toolbar

Tags: css, extjs, colors, toolbar

I have a simple toolbar in ExtJS that only contains buttons, I would like to know how to change the color of those buttons by using cls property maybe

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can override the base css classes applied to toobar like this:

```
    .x-btn-default-toolbar-small
    {
        border-color: #90B5E5;
        border-style: solid;
        background-color: #B7CEEE;
    }
```

Comment: but I need to apply this to only one toolbar, not all